ASP.NET Core JWT and Identity - Program.cs configuration
I am developing an ASP.NET Core 8.0 project. I use Onion architecture in my project. I use both JWT and Identity as security. When I generate tokens on the API side and send a request from postman, I can access the data, so it works smoothly. On the MVC side, I perform the login process and I can access the data. However, there is a problem like this. If I use the following configuration in Program.cs, it redirects to Account/Login page instead of Login/Index. This is not an index I defined.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Error404";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.Name = "AuthToken";
});

If I use it this way, it returns to Login/Index page but does not log in, it goes to Home/Index and returns to Login/Index again
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Error404";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.Name = "AuthToken";
});

My other codes:
All Program.cs Configuration:
using Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Persistence.Context;
using PresentationUI.Handlers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Error404";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.Name = "AuthToken";
});

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddTransient<AuthorizedHttpClientHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("AuthorizedClient")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthorizedHttpClientHandler>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

LoginController.cs:
using Domain.Entities;
using DtoLayer.LoginDtos;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PresentationUI.Models;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace PresentationUI.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;

        public LoginController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CreateLoginDto createLoginDto)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(createLoginDto.UserName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, createLoginDto.Password, true);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Confirmation");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var login = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(createLoginDto.UserName, createLoginDto.Password, true, true);

                        if (login.Succeeded)
                        {
                            if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "User"))
                            {
                                var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                                var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(createLoginDto), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7125/api/Login", content);
                                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                    var tokenModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JwtResponseModel>(jsonData, new JsonSerializerOptions
                                    {
                                        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                                    });

                                    if (tokenModel != null && tokenModel.Token != null)
                                    {
                                        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("AuthToken", tokenModel.Token, new CookieOptions
                                        {
                                            HttpOnly = true,
                                            Secure = true,
                                        });
                                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Bu sayfaya erişim izniniz bulunmamaktadır.");
                                return View();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (login.IsLockedOut)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Fazla sayıda hatalı giriş yaptığınız için hesabınız kilitlendi. Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyiniz. Şifrenizi hatırlamıyorsanız 'Şifremi Unuttum' kısmından yeni bir şifre belirleyebilirsiniz.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Kullanıcı Adı veya Şifre Hatalı");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Fazla sayıda hatalı giriş yaptığınız için hesabınız kilitlendi. Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyiniz. Şifrenizi hatırlamıyorsanız 'Şifremi Unuttum' kısmından yeni bir şifre belirleyebilirsiniz.");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Kullanıcı Adı veya Şifre Hatalı");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Böyle Bir Hesap Bulunamadı");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}

HomeController.cs:
using DtoLayer.BrandDtos;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PresentationUI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("AuthorizedClient");
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7125/api/Brand");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultBrandDto>>(jsonData);
                return View(values);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}

AuthorizedHttpClientHandler.cs
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace PresentationUI.Handlers
{
    public class AuthorizedHttpClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AuthorizedHttpClientHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["AuthToken"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}


Your "MVC front" project doesn't really have JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme. This jwt scheme only should be added to the "back api" project.
"AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.options..." is not right. This creates another cookie named "jwt" .But it is not the real JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.
Instead, you could configure the "Asp.Net Core Identity" cookie like following:
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Error404";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    // This name shouldn't be changed. The cookie "authtoken" is only for storage purpose. Not for authentication.
    //options.Cookie.Name = "AuthToken";
});

